# unitary decomposition of diagonal matrices

Tags: matrices, diagonalization

Let $D \in \mathbb{R^{n,n}}$ be a diagonal Matrix with diagonal entries $d_{ii} \neq 0$.
Let $\tilde{D} \in \mathbb{R}^{n,n}$ be a diagonal matrix with the same diagonal entries that could be transposed in any way (for example $\tilde{d}_{11}=d_{22}$). Does there exist a unitary matrix $U$ such that $$UDU^H=\tilde{D}$$?

Comment: What did you try? Hint: permutation matrices are unitary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your condition. It seems that your are looking for something like
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\1&0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a&0\\0&b
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\1&0
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
b&0\\0&a
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\1&0
\end{pmatrix}$ is unitary. For general $n\times n$ matrices we can use matrix blocks to construct such examples.